# Comparing two NumPy arrays for equality, element-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, elementwise-operations

What is the simplest way to compare two NumPy arrays for equality (where equality is defined as: A = B iff for all indices i: `A[i] == B[i]`)?

Simply using `==` gives me a boolean array:

```
 >>> numpy.array([1,1,1]) == numpy.array([1,1,1])

array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Do I have to `and` the elements of this array to determine if the arrays are equal, or is there a simpler way to compare?

Answer (score 653, accepted):

```
(A==B).all()
```

test if all values of array (A==B) are True.

Note: maybe you also want to test A and B shape, such as `A.shape == B.shape`

**Special cases and alternatives** (from dbaupp's answer and yoavram's comment)

It should be noted that:

- this solution can have a strange behavior in a particular case: if either `A` or `B` is empty  and the other one contains a single element, then it return `True`. For some reason, the comparison `A==B` returns an empty array, for which the `all` operator returns `True`.
- Another risk is if `A` and `B` don't have the same shape and aren't broadcastable, then this approach will raise an error.

In conclusion, if you have a doubt about `A` and `B` shape or simply want to be safe: use one of the specialized functions:

```
np.array_equal(A,B)  # test if same shape, same elements values
np.array_equiv(A,B)  # test if broadcastable shape, same elements values
np.allclose(A,B,...) # test if same shape, elements have close enough values
```

Comment: You've got a good point, but in the case I have a doubt on the shape I usually prefer to directly test it, before the value. Then the error is clearly on the shapes which have a completely different meaning than having different values. But that probably depends on each use-case

Comment: another risk is if the arrays contains nan. In that case you will get False because nan != nan

Comment: Good to point it out. However, I think this is logical because `nan!=nan` implies that `array(nan)!=array(nan)`.

Comment: I do not understand this behavior:

`import numpy as np`
`H = 1/np.sqrt(2)*np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]]) #hadamard matrix`
`np.array_equal(H.dot(H.T.conj()), np.eye(len(H))) # checking if H is an unitary matrix or not`

H is an unitary matrix, so H x `H.T.conj` is an identity matrix. But `np.array_equal` returns False

Comment: This should be put in another question. But the answer is simple, the values of the H * H.T.conj is close but not equals to an id matrix due to numeric precision: use `np.allclose`

Comment: Could you please explain the situation when I need to compare values of one array `array1` to the values of `array2` and `array3`, so that:
each value of `array1` have to be tested if she falls inbetween value of `array2` and `array3`. At the same time I have to test each `array1` value through all pairs of `array2` and `array3`, but this pairs must be on the same position

Comment: (array1<array3).all() and (array1>array2).all()

Answer (score 133):

The `(A==B).all()` solution is very neat, but there are some built-in functions for this task. Namely [`array_equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html), [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose) and [`array_equiv`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equiv.html#numpy.array_equiv).

(Although, some quick testing with `timeit` seems to indicate that the `(A==B).all()` method is the fastest, which is a little peculiar, given it has to allocate a whole new array.)

Comment: you're right, except that if one of the compared arrays is empty you'll get the wrong answer with `(A==B).all()`. For example, try: `(np.array([1])==np.array([])).all()`, it gives `True`, while `np.array_equal(np.array([1]), np.array([]))` gives `False`

Comment: I just discovered this performance difference too. It's strange because if you have 2 arrays that are completely different `(a==b).all()` is still faster than `np.array_equal(a, b)` (which could have just checked a single element and exited).

Comment: `np.array_equal` also works with `lists of arrays` and `dicts of arrays`. This might be a reason for a slower performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the function `allclose`, that is what I needed for *numerical* calculations. It compares the equality of vectors within a **tolerance**. :)

Comment: Note that `np.array_equiv([1,1,1], 1) is True`. This is because: _Shape consistent means they are either the same shape, or one input array can be broadcasted to create the same shape as the other one._

Answer (score 23):

If you want to check if two arrays have the same `shape` AND `elements` you should  use `np.array_equal` as it is the method recommended in the documentation.

> Performance-wise don't expect that any equality check will beat another, as there is not much room to optimize `comparing two elements`. Just for the sake, i still did some tests.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

A = np.zeros((300, 300, 3))
B = np.zeros((300, 300, 3))
C = np.ones((300, 300, 3))

timeit.timeit(stmt='(A==B).all()', setup='from __main__ import A, B', number=10**5)
timeit.timeit(stmt='np.array_equal(A, B)', setup='from __main__ import A, B, np', number=10**5)
timeit.timeit(stmt='np.array_equiv(A, B)', setup='from __main__ import A, B, np', number=10**5)
> 51.5094
> 52.555
> 52.761
```

So pretty much equal, no need to talk about the speed.

The `(A==B).all()` behaves pretty much as the following code snippet:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
print all([x[i]==y[i] for i in range(len(x))])
> True
```

Answer (score 17):

Let's measure the performance by using the following piece of code.

```
import numpy as np
import time

exec_time0 = []
exec_time1 = []
exec_time2 = []

sizeOfArray = 5000
numOfIterations = 200

for i in xrange(numOfIterations):

    A = np.random.randint(0,255,(sizeOfArray,sizeOfArray))
    B = np.random.randint(0,255,(sizeOfArray,sizeOfArray))

    a = time.clock() 
    res = (A==B).all()
    b = time.clock()
    exec_time0.append( b - a )

    a = time.clock() 
    res = np.array_equal(A,B)
    b = time.clock()
    exec_time1.append( b - a )

    a = time.clock() 
    res = np.array_equiv(A,B)
    b = time.clock()
    exec_time2.append( b - a )

print 'Method: (A==B).all(),       ', np.mean(exec_time0)
print 'Method: np.array_equal(A,B),', np.mean(exec_time1)
print 'Method: np.array_equiv(A,B),', np.mean(exec_time2)
```

**Output**

```
Method: (A==B).all(),        0.03031857
Method: np.array_equal(A,B), 0.030025185
Method: np.array_equiv(A,B), 0.030141515
```

According to the results above, the numpy methods seem to be faster than the combination of the **==** operator and the **all()** method and by comparing the numpy methods **the fastest** one seems to be the **numpy.array_equal** method.

Comment: You should use a larger array size that takes at least a second to compile to increase the experiment accuracy.

Comment: Does this also reproduce when order of comparison is changed? or reiniting A and B to random each time? This difference might also be explained from memory caching of A and B cells.

Comment: There's no meaningful difference between these timings.

Answer (score 10):

Usually two arrays will have some small numeric errors,

You can use `numpy.allclose(A,B)`, instead of `(A==B).all()`. This returns a bool True/False

Answer (score 5):

Now use `np.array_equal`. From documentation:

```
np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 2])
True
np.array_equal(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]))
True
np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
False
np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 4])
False
```

Comment: `np.array_equal` documentation link: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html

Answer (score 2):

On top of the other answers, you can now use an assertion:

```
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(x, y)
```

You also have similar function such as `numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal()`

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness. I will add the
pandas approach for comparing two arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(0.0, 10.2, 0.12)
b = np.arange(0.0, 10.2, 0.12)
ap = pd.DataFrame(a)
bp = pd.DataFrame(b)

ap.equals(bp)
True
```

FYI: In case you are looking of How to
compare Vectors, Arrays or Dataframes in R.
You just you can use:

```
identical(iris1, iris2)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(array1, array2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: what is the `pd.` then? You should mention you're adding additional dependency of Pandas.