# Python Array Creation: Difference between a = numpy.array((1,2,3)) and a = numpy.array([1,2,3])

Tags: arrays, numpy

When creating an array using numpy, what is the difference between:
1) a = numpy.array((1,2,3)) 
and 2) a = numpy.array([1,2,3])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the output.

```
a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array([1,2,3])
(a == b).all() # True
```

The objects that those two commands create are identical.

You can also test equivalence with `np.array_equal(a,b)`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality) for more info.

### Timing

Timing these two expressions has the tuple method with a marginal (insignificant?) advantage, for example in an iPython shell:

```
In [1]: %timeit a = np.array((1,2,3))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit a = np.array([1,2,3])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 µs per loop
```

Running tests on longer (1 million entries) lists/tuples gives consistently marginal advantage to tuples.

Comment: Thanks Farenorth! That's very helpful.