# Greater of two numpy arrays, element-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, elementwise-operations

I have two numpy arrays and I'm trying to find the greater of them (element wise, i.e. all elements should be greater)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([4,5,6])
b = np.array([7,8,9])

if b > a:
    print 'True'
```

But I'm not getting the desired output and getting an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two numpy arrays for equality, element-wise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if all(b>a):
   print 'True'
```

For multi-dimensional arrays, use:

```
if np.all(b>a):
   print 'True'
```

However `all()` is faster for single dimension arrays and may be useful if your arrays are very large:

```
>>> timeit('a = np.array([4,5,6]); b = np.array([7,8,9]); all(a>b)',number=100000,setup='import numpy as np')
0.34104180335998535
>>> timeit('a = np.array([4,5,6]); b = np.array([7,8,9]); np.all(a>b)',number=100000,setup='import numpy as np')
0.9201719760894775
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.all()`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([4,5,6])

In [3]: b = np.array([7,8,9])

In [4]: np.all(b > a)
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

`b > a` produces an array containing `True`/`False` values.

However, Python can't determine whether NumPy arrays with more than one element should be `True` or `False`. How should an array such as `array([True, False, True])` be evaluated? A `ValueError` is raised because of the potential ambiguity.

Instead, you need to check whether *all* of the values in `b > a` are `True`. Use NumPy's `all()` to do this:

```
if (b > a).all():
    print 'True'
```