# shortcut evaluation of numpy's array comparison

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy if I want to compare two arrays, say for example I want to test if all elements in A are less than values in B, I use `if (A < B).all():`. But in practice this requires allocation and evaluation of complete array `C = A < B` and then calling `C.all()` on it. This is a bit of waste. Is there any way to 'shortcut' the comparison, i.e. directly evaluate `A < B` element by element (without allocation and calculation of temporary `C`) and stop and return `False` when first invalid element comparison is found?

Comment: Does this 'waste' noticeably impact performance?

Comment: In my case not much. But in general it could have impact - I bet that allocating extra 1000x1000x1000 array could harm your performance. I was asking out of mere curiosity, I believe this shortcut evaluation would be very handy. There are function `allclose()` which I believe stop when first noncompliant element is found. So I was surprised that I did not find `allequal(a,b)`, `allless(a,b)` and `allgreater(a,b)` which all would be very popular in their use I believe, because `if (A<B).all():` and similar is quite common pattern.

Comment: Having looked at the numpy source while I don't think there is support for shortcutting the A<B on the first `True` the `.all()` uses a bool AND check which should shortcut. But that won't help with the memory allocation.

Comment: There is `np.array_equal` (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise) but no corresponding less. However, that function does not shortcut either (it's a wrapper around `(A==B).all()` with additional checks).

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html go ahead ;-)

Comment: As I have just found by looking at the `numpy` source, we have `allequal(a,b)` function (to partly correct my previous comment) but it does not shortcut the evaluation, which is pity.

Comment: You may be able to wring your own function using cython \ numba for better performance. But you'll probably have to make them type specific for the speed gain. So you would be sacrificing flexibility for speed.

Comment: So you are asking for compiled functions that implement `allless`, `anyless`, `allless_or_equal`, `any_not_equal`, `any_gt`, `all_ge`, etc?  This is a big step away from the building-block model that makes `numpy` so convenient (and fast enough for general problems).

Comment: @hpaulj: I do not think that we need all the combinations, only a few of them would do. Consider if we had `all_lt(a,b)`. Then we would have for free the following three `all_gt`, `any_le`, `any_ge` because of the equivalences: `not all_lt(a,b) <==> any_ge(a,b)` and `all_lt(b, a) <==> all_gt(a,b)` and `not all_lt(b,a) <==> any_le(a,b)`. If then we add `any_lt(a,b)` we would get another three for free. And then we would need only `allequal(a,b)` which is already in `numpy` but is not using shortcut evaluation. So only two more functions (e.g. `all_lt` and `any_lt`) would cover all our needs.

Comment: Come on people, trying to persuade one into statement "well, I do not actually need it" is too cheap trick. I do not need my car either, of course, I have two legs and can walk. :)

Comment: What about `a<b<=c` (on an element by element basis)?  Or `(a<b) and (b<=c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain Python `and` and `or` use shortcut evaluation, but `numpy` does not.

```
(A < B).all()
```

uses `numpy` building blocks, the broadcasting, the element by element comparison with `<` and the `all` reduction.  The `<` works just other binary operations, plus, times, and, or, gt, le, etc.  And `all` is like other reduction methods, `any`, `max`, `sum`, `mean`, and can operate on the whole array or by rows or by columns.

It is possible to write a function that combines the `all` and `<` into one iteration, but it would be difficult to get the generality that I just described.

But if you must implement an iterative solution, with a shortcut action, and do it fast, I'd suggest developing the idea with `nditer`, and then compile it with `cython`.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html is a good tutorial on using `nditer`, and it takes you through using it in `cython`.  `nditer` takes care of broadcasting and iteration, letting you concentrate on the comparison and any shortcutting.

Here's a sketch of an iterator that could be cast into `cython`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(4)[:,None]
b = np.arange(2,5)[None,:]
c = np.array(True)
it = np.nditer([a, b, c], flags=['reduce_ok'],
    op_flags = [['readonly'], ['readonly'],['readwrite']])
for x, y, z in it:
    z[...] = x<y
    if not z:
        print('>',x,y)
        break
    else:
        print(x,y)
print(z)
```

with a sample run:

```
1420:~/mypy$ python stack34852272.py 
(array(0), array(2))
(array(0), array(3))
(array(0), array(4))
(array(1), array(2))
(array(1), array(3))
(array(1), array(4))
('>', array(2), array(2))
False
```

Start with a default `False`, and a different `break` condition and you get a shortcutting `any`.  Generalizing the test to handle `<`, `<=`, etc will be more work.

Get something like this working in Python, and then try it in Cython.  If you have trouble with that step, come back with a new question.  SO has a good base of Cython users.

Answer (score 1):

How large are you arrays?  I would imagine they are very large, e.g. `A.shape = (1000000)` or larger before performance becomes an issue.  Would you consider using numpy [views](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)?

Instead of comparing `(A < B).all()` or `(A < B).any()` you can try defining a view, such as `(A[:10] < B[:10]).all()`.  Here's a simple loop that might work:

```
k = 0
while( (A[k*10: (k+1)*10] < B[k*10: (k+1)*10] ).all() ):
    k += 1
```

Instead of 10 you can use 100 or `10**3` segment size you wish.  Obviously if your segment size is 1, you are saying:

```
k = 0
while ( A[k] < B[k] ):
    k+= 1
```

Sometimes, comparing the entire array can become memory intensive.  If `A`  and `B` have length of 10000 and I need to compare each pair of elements, I am going to run out of space.

Comment: Splitting of a large array with views is a very clever idea so I am upvoting that. But it is a terrible hack of something that I believe should be naturally in the numpy library.