# numpy array_equal gives 'NoneType' object not callable

Tags: arrays, numpy, nonetype

I am using numpy in an Anaconda virtual env , Python 3.3.2
The following code gives me a 'NoneType' object not callable error

I read through this post but I did not find a solution [Comparing two numpy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise/10582030#10582030)

```
np.array_equal(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]))
```

I get the same error with the array_equiv method below

```
np.array_equiv(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]))
```

Comment: Could you try `print(type(np.array), repr(np.array))` and edit your question to show the results?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using anaconda with a 3D cad program so it may be the CAD program that is causing the issues.     `type(array1)` gives `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: The end goal is to write an if statement `if np.array_equiv(array1, array2)`

Comment: I didn't ask about `type(array1)` (which isn't even in your code..)

Comment: You need to find the `None` object or attribute.  `None(np.array([1,2,]))` produces the same error.

Comment: @hpaulj: I wondered if it was `_equal` or `_equiv` too, but if the OP is right and it happens with both, I thought it's more likely that `array` has been rebound than either of those.  But since the mention of `array1` makes me suspect we're not seeing the real code which generates the errors, all bets are off..

Comment: in this 3D CAD program, I am unable to `print(type(np.array))` . Instead I use `self.theLw.WriteLine(str(type(array)))` which prints to console `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: `None(np.array([1,2,]))` does produce a 'None type' object not callable error