# Boolean expression with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-expression

Basically i am trying out  boolean expressions with numpy arrays , for example something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,0,1])
b = np.array([0,1,1])
c = np.array([1,0,1])

if (a ==b) or (a==c):
    d = [2,5,5]
else : d = [1,5,5]
print d
```

This returns an error

**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

What would be the correct way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the condition should read:

```
if (a==b).all() or (a==c).all():
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)