# Check if two numpy arrays are identical

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a bunch of arrays, including `x` and `y`, and I want to check if they're equal. Generally, I can just use `np.all(x == y)` (barring some dumb corner cases which I'm ignoring now).

However this evaluates the *entire* array of `(x == y)`, which is usually not needed. My arrays are really large, and I have a lot of them, and the probability of two arrays being equal is small, so in all likelihood, I really only need to evaluate a very small portion of `(x == y)` before the `all` function *could* return False, so this is not an optimal solution for me.

I've tried using the builtin `all` function, in combination with `itertools.izip`: `all(val1==val2 for val1,val2 in itertools.izip(x, y))`

However, that just seems much slower in the case that two arrays *are* equal, that overall, it's stil not worth using over `np.all`. I presume because of the builtin `all`'s general-purposeness. And `np.all` doesn't work on generators.

Is there a way to do what I want in a more speedy manner?

I know this question is similar to previously asked questions (e.g. [Comparing two numpy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)) but they specifically don't cover the case of early termination.

Comment: what about this function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html

Comment: @Thomas: That function just calls `np.all` internally, so it's kind of useless. (I would indeed expect a function specifically for this purpose to do short-circuiting, but alas, it does not.)

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. A numpy-internal function would be your only chance, I guess, as any looping outside of numpy is almost bound to be slower. Have you considered contacting the developers directly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Until this is implemented in numpy natively you can write your own function and jit-compile it with [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def arrays_equal(a, b):
    if a.shape != b.shape:
        return False
    for ai, bi in zip(a.flat, b.flat):
        if ai != bi:
            return False
    return True


a = np.random.rand(10, 20, 30)
b = np.random.rand(10, 20, 30)


%timeit np.all(a==b)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.82 µs per loop
%timeit arrays_equal(a, a)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.89 µs per loop
%timeit arrays_equal(a, b)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 691 ns per loop
```

Worst case performance (arrays equal) is equivalent to `np.all` and in case of early stopping the compiled function has the potential to outperform `np.all` a lot.

Comment: I like it, but for my test arrays, if they are equal, it still takes about 1.6 times  longer than `np.all(arr1==arr2)`. (For reference, `arr1 = np.ones((1000000,), dtype=bool)`, 'arr2 = np.ones((1000000,), dtype=bool)', 'arr2[100000] = False`). (Make sure to lower the number on your timeit to something like 1000.)

Comment: @acdr When I use your arrays `np.all` takes 1.8 ms and `arrays_equal` takes 183 µs. If I compare `arr1` against itself both take about 1.8 ms. Maybe this discrepancy is caused by our systems? I have Python 3.5.2, numpy 1.12.1 and numba 0.27.0.

Comment: Might be. I'm running much older stuff than you in general: Python 2.7.10.2, numpy 1.9.1, numba 0.20.0

Comment: `Np.all` does not have branch instructions. In the case where arrays are identical, you'd expect a function without branches to be faster than a function with branches. That's probably where the discrepancy comes from. You should look at your use cases and decide what is more likely to happen. This is still python, and not assembly, so microoptimizations may not always have the effect you want.

Comment: @dangom Your point can be easily verified by writing a branchless version of above's `array_compare`. I did so and found that you are right - in the worst case scenario the branchless version is slightly faster. However, `np.all` performs equivalently to the branching version. (This casts doubt on your assertion that `np.all` does not have branch instructions.) Anyway, the point here is not to optimize the worst case but the *likely* case, which allegedly can benefit from short-circuit termination. I suspect that numba 0.20 produces less optimal code than numba 0.27 in the particular situation

Comment: It is in numpy now, right? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html

Comment: @JannPoppinga unfortunately, no; at least not in this function. `array_equal` just [calls `np.all(a==b)` internally](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2378).

Answer (score 1):

Adding short-circuit logic to array comparisons is apparently being discussed on the [numpy page on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8528), and will thus presumably be available in a future version of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Probably someone who understands the underlying data structure could optimize this or explain whether it's reliable/safe/good practice, but it seems to work.

```
np.all(a==b)
Out[]: True

memoryview(a.data)==memoryview(b.data)
Out[]: True

%timeit np.all(a==b)
The slowest run took 10.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.2 µs per loop

%timeit memoryview(a.data)==memoryview(b.data)
The slowest run took 8.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.85 µs per loop
```

If I understand this correctly, `ndarray.data` creates a pointer to the data buffer and `memoryview` creates a native python type that can be short-circuited out of the buffer.

I think.

EDIT: further testing shows it may not be as big a time-improvement as shown.  previously `a=b=np.eye(5)`

```
a=np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100))

b=a.copy()

%timeit np.all(a==b)
The slowest run took 6.70 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 µs per loop

%timeit memoryview(a.data)==memoryview(b.data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.1 µs per loop

np.all(a==b)
Out[]: True

memoryview(a.data)==memoryview(b.data)
Out[]: True
```

Comment: Doesn't this just test if the two arrays are actually different names for the same object, rather than two different objects that have the same values?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.  Tested using `.copy()` as above and then sequentially manipulating both random arrays above in identical ways.

Comment: Didn't work for me, with a current Anaconda version of numpy. Maybe it just doesn't like NaNs.

Comment: @matanster not sure what you tried, but in standard usage NaN != NaN

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I know it is the poor answer but it seems there is no easy way for this. Numpy Creators should fix it. I suggest:

```
def compare(a, b):
    if len(a) > 0 and not np.array_equal(a[0], b[0]):
        return False
    if len(a) > 15 and not np.array_equal(a[:15], b[:15]):
        return False
    if len(a) > 200 and not np.array_equal(a[:200], b[:200]):
        return False
    return np.array_equal(a, b)
```

:)

Comment: because nobody else said, that it can't be done with numpy, and the problem is still open I think

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43975611/501011) has been accepted and uses numpy

Comment: it uses numba. If you're not happy with someone's telling honestly there is no better way to do sth, you can flag it, but my answet at least contains creative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really an answer as I haven't checked if it break-circuits, but:

[assert_array_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html).

From the documentation:

> Raises an AssertionError if two `array_like` objects are not equal.

`Try` `Except` it if not on a performance sensitive code path.

Or follow the underlying source code, maybe it's efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the underlying code looks to just be a wrapper for `x == y`, with a few extra steps added in for some corner cases (like `NaN`s and `Inf`s).

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the original problem to three parts: "(1) My arrays are **really large**, and (2) I have **a lot of them**, and (3) the **probability of two arrays being equal is small**"

All the solutions (to date) are focused on part (1) - optimizing the performance of each equality check, and some improve this performance by factor of 10. Points (2) and (3) are ignored. Comparing each pair has O(n^2) complexity, which can become huge for a lot of matrices, while needles as the probability of being duplicates is very small.

The check can become much faster with the following general algorithm -

- fast hash of each array O(n)
- check equality only for arrays with the same hash

A good hash is almost unique, so the number of keys can easily be a very large fraction of n. On average, number of arrays with the same hash will be very small, and almost 1 in some cases. Duplicate arrays will have the same hash, while having the same hash doesn't guarantee they are duplicates. In that sense, the algorithm will catch all the duplicates. Comparing images only with the same hash significantly reduces the number of comparisons, which becomes almost O(n)

For my problem, I had to check duplicates within ~1 million integer arrays, each with 10k elements. Optimizing only the array equality check (with [@MB-F](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/805941/anask) solution) estimated run time was 5 days. With hashing first it finished in minutes. (I used array sum as the hash, that was suited for my arrays characteristics)

Some psuedo-python code

```py
def fast_hash(arr) -> int:
    pass

def arrays_equal(arr1, arr2) -> bool:
    pass

def make_hash_dict(array_stack, hush_fn=np.sum):

    hash_dict = defaultdict(list)
    hashes = np.squeeze(np.apply_over_axes(hush_fn, array_stack, range(1, array_stack.ndim)))
    for idx, hash_val in enumerate(hashes):
        hash_dict[hash_val].append(idx)

    return hash_dict

def get_duplicate_sets(hash_dict, array_stack):

    duplicate_sets = []
    for hash_key, ind_list in hash_dict.items():
        if len(ind_list) == 1:
            continue

        all_duplicates = []
        for idx1 in range(len(ind_list)):
            v1 = ind_list[idx1]
            if v1 in all_duplicates:
                continue

            arr1 = array_stack[v1]
            curr_duplicates = []
            for idx2 in range(idx1+1, len(ind_list)):
                v2 = ind_list[idx2]
                arr2 = array_stack[v2]
                if arrays_equal(arr1, arr2):
                    if len(curr_duplicates) == 0:
                        curr_duplicates.append(v1)
                    curr_duplicates.append(v2)
            
            if len(curr_duplicates) > 0:
                all_duplicates.extend(curr_duplicates)
                duplicate_sets.append(curr_duplicates)

    return duplicate_sets
```

The variable `duplicate_sets` is a list of lists, each internal list contains indices of all the same duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all elements of the arrays and check if they are equal.
If the arrays are most likely not equal it will return much faster than the .all function. 
Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([1, 3, 4])

areEqual = True

for x in range(0, a.size-1):
        if a[x] != b[x]:
                areEqual = False
                break
        else:
               print "a[x] is equal to b[x]\n"

if areEqual:
        print "The tables are equal\n"
else:
        print "The tables are not equal\n"
```

Comment: This is effectively what `all(val1==val2 for val1,val2 in itertools.izip(x, y))` does: it loops through `x` and `y`, returning pairs of `val1` and `val2`, checks if they're the same, and passes the result to `all`, which will return `False` as soon as it finds a non-equal pair.

Comment: Oh i see, i thought it goes through all elements of the arrays.

Comment: Luckily, the builtin `all` does do circuit breaking, unlike `np.all`. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Kühn wrote in a comment to your post, `array_equal` is a function which should solve the problem. It is described in [Numpy's API reference](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html).