# check two arrays for matching elements given the same index and return number of matches

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays, is there a numpy non-loop way to check if each ith index matches between the arrays, aka check for every i if a[i]==b[i]?

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
b = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
Output:  0 matches
```

I expect this has already been asked but I could not find what I was looking for, apologies if it is.

Comment: What do you mean by _"...each ith index matches between the arrays..."_? Specifically, what do you expect to be returned by such a function?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two numpy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

Comment: Bad phrasing, sorry. Checking for each ith element in each array if a[i] == b[i]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.arange(len(a))[a==b]
```

It creates a new array from 0 to length `a` representing the indices.  Then use `a==b` to slice the array, returning the indices where `a` and `b` are the same.

Additionally from @Reblochon-Masque:

You can use `numpy.where` to extract the indices where two values meet a specified condition:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = numpy.array([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6])
numpy.where(a==b)
```

#### output:

```
(array([3, 6]),)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `numpy.where` to extract the indices where two values meet a specified condition:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = numpy.array([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6])
numpy.where(a==b)
```

#### output:

```
(array([3, 6]),)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out np.where but was not exactly correct. Was computing a[np.where(a==b)] and other incorrect answers.

Answer (score 3):

Another variation to other answers:

```
np.flatnonzero(a == b)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could try something like:**

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,6])

b = np.array([8,2,10,2,7,4,10,4,9,8])

np.where(a == b)

(array([1, 3, 5, 7]),)
```