# Keras: correctness of model and issues with custom metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, metrics

I'm trying to create the autoencoder for processes. Each process is a sequence of events and each event represents as number from 0 to 461 (and important, that events with close numbers are not similar, numbers were given out randomly). Each process has length 60 and total count of processes is `n`. So my input data is array `(n, 60)`.

First, I created the Embedding layer to convert events numbers to one-hot representation:

```
BLOCK_LEN = 60
EVENTS_CNT = 462

input = Input(shape=(BLOCK_LEN,))
embedded = Embedding(input_dim=EVENTS_CNT+1, input_length=BLOCK_LEN, output_dim=200)(input)
emb_model = Model(input, embedded)
emb_model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 60)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 60, 200)           92600     
=================================================================
Total params: 92,600
Trainable params: 92,600
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Second, I created the main Seq2Seq model (using [that library](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/seq2seq)):

```
seq_model = Seq2Seq(batch_input_shape=(None, BLOCK_LEN, 200), hidden_dim=200, output_length=BLOCK_LEN, output_dim=EVENTS_CNT)
```

Resulting model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(emb_model)
model.add(seq_model)
model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
model_1 (Model)              (None, 60, 200)           92600     
_________________________________________________________________
model_12 (Model)             (None, 60, 462)           1077124   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,169,724
Trainable params: 1,169,724
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Also I have my own accuracy metric (because lib's accuracy doesn't appropriate for my data):

```
def symbol_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    isEqual = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, y_pred), K.floatx())
    return K.mean(isEqual)
```

And compile:

```
model.compile(loss=tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy,optimizer='adam', target_tensors=[tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 60])], metrics=[symbol_acc])
```

Why compile looks like that: At first model had one more layer `model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(EVENTS_CNT, activation='softmax')))` and compile was `model.compile(loss=custom_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=[symbol_acc])`. But such model produced an error "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2714, 60)". Now all shapes are suitable.

But now I have new **problem** (key moment of my story): shapes in metric `symbol_acc` are dirrefent:

> Shapes (symbol_acc): (?, 60) (?, ?, 462)

So the `true` array has shape `(?, 60)` and predicted - `(?, ?, 462)`. Each value in `true` 60 values is a number from 0 to 461 (represents the true number of event) and each value in `predicted` 60 ones is a vector of size 462 of probability distribution for each number from 0 to 461 (for each of 462 events) (for each of 462 events). I want to make `true` the same shape as `predicted`: for each of 60 values make vector of size 462 with 1 on the event number position and 0s on the others.

So my questions:

1. How to change shape of array in metric if before fitting model I have no data? Maxumum that I got is `K.gather(K.eye(462), tf.cast(number, tf.int32))`: that code creates one-hot array with 1 in `number` position. But I don't understand how I can apply it to array without knowing this array.
2. Maybe there is more simple way to solve that problem?

I'm new in keras and NNs, so I don't sure that all steps are correct. If you see any mistake please report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I tested before, using `target_tensors` will not work unless its shape is the same as the model's predicted shape.

So, this general rule cannot be violated:

> Your output data must have the same shape as your model's ouptut

This makes `y_true` and `y_pred` certainly have the same shape.

What you need is to adapt your output data to the shape of your model, using [to_categorical()](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical).

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
one_hot_X = to_categorical(X_train,462)
```

With that you simply train your model normally, without having to create workarounds in losses and accuracies:

```
model.fit(X_train, one_hot_X,...)
```

---

**If you run into memory problems** by doing this, you may consider creating a generator that will convert only part of the data for each batch:

```
def batch_generator(batch_size):
    
    while True: #keras generators must be infinite

        #you may want to manually shuffle X_train here

        for i in range(len(X_train)//batch_size): #make sure len is a multiple of batch_size
            
            x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            y = to_categorical(x,462)

            yield (x,y)
```

Train with:

```
model.fit_generator(batch_generator(size),....)
```

---

### Fixing your accuracy for this case

Now that we know better what you're doing, your accuracy should use `K.argmax` to get exact results (and not to consider 462 options while it should be 1, correct or not)

(My old answer was wrong, because I forgot that `y_true` is exact, but `y_pred` is approximated).

```
def symbol_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.argmax(y_true) #this gets the class as an integer (comparable to X_train)
    y_pred = K.argmax(y_pred) #transforming (any,60,462) into (any,60)

    isEqual = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, y_pred), K.floatx())
    return K.mean(isEqual)
```

**Just a small correction:**

Embeddings don't create "one-hot" representation, they just create a multi-feature representation. (One hot is strictly for the cases where only one element in the vector is one, but embeddings are free to any value in any element).

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much! It is very clear for me now! Thank you for all your explanations, fixions and corrections. And idea with batch_generator is brilliant. Am I right that batch_generator must return yield (x,y)?

Comment: And is it true that I need to add `TimeDistributed(Dense(EVENTS_CNT, activation='softmax'))` layer again to get probabilities in predictions?

Comment: `yield`, right!! Sorry :) --- `TimeDistributed`, you may use it, but no, it's not needed. (You should consider using at least an activation function that outputs between 0 and 1. For categorical classifications, the best is "softmax". For multiclasses, "sigmoid", but this doesn't seem to be your case).

Comment: I'd say all you need is a final "softmax" activation (because your problem is a categorical classification with only one correct class). You may add a `Dense` layer, this will give your model more power, but who knows how much power is necessary before it starts overfitting? If that layer will better or worsen your model, only experiment will tell. `Dense` layers do not require `TimeDistributed`, even with 3D data. (In the past, `TimeDistributed` would be necessary, though).

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you very much once again!