# How to check whether two three dimensional numpy arrays are the same?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array with shape `(1,x,1)` and the second one also with shape `(1,x,1)`. I wonder how can I check whether they are the same? Examples:

1.
First:

```
[[[ 2]
  [ 3]
  [ 4]
  [ 5]
  [ 6]
  [ 7]
  [ 8]
  [ 9]
  [ 4]
  [ 6]
  [10]]]
```

Second:

```
[[[ 2]
  [ 3]
  [ 4]
  [ 5]
  [ 6]
  [ 7]
  [ 8]
  [ 9]
  [ 4]
  [ 6]
  [10]]]
```

Response: True

2.

First:

```
[[[ 2]
  [ 3]
  [ 4]
  [ 5]
  [ 6]
  [ 7]
  [ 8]
  [ 9]
  [ 4]]]
```

Second:

```
[[[ 1]
  [ 2]
  [ 3]
  [ 5]
  [ 6]
  [ 2]
  [ 8]
  [ 3]
  [ 5]]]
```

Response: False

Comment: `np.allclose` is easy to use, and better if the arrays are floats.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html

Answer (score 0):

There is already a SO question with that topic and a good answer by @Juh_ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise#10580782).

The solution:

```py
(A==B).all()
```

Comment: `np.array_equal` will work, too?

Comment: Yes it should, it's also mentioned in the answer :)