# Why does using "==" return a Series instead of bool in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-indexing

I just can't figure out what "==" means at the second line:
- It is not a test, there is no if statement...
- It is not a variable declaration...

I've never seen this before, the thing is `data.ctage==cat` is a pandas Series and not a test...

```
for cat in data["categ"].unique():
    subset = data[data.categ == cat] # Création du sous-échantillon
    print("-"*20)
    print('Catégorie : ' + cat)
    print("moyenne:\n",subset['montant'].mean())
    print("mediane:\n",subset['montant'].median())
    print("mode:\n",subset['montant'].mode())
    print("VAR:\n",subset['montant'].var())
    print("EC:\n",subset['montant'].std())
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    subset["montant"].hist(bins=30) # Crée l'histogramme
    plt.show() # Affiche l'histogramme
```

Comment: Maybe they're doing an element-wise comparison of two numpy arrays, and using the resulting boolean array as a selector to data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise
Pandas is weird.

Comment: It is a mask like `positive_X = X[X > 0]` from numpy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is testing each element of `data.categ` for equality with `cat`.  That produces a vector of True/False values. This is passed as in indexer to `data[]`, which returns the rows from `data` that correspond to the True values in the vector.

To summarize, the whole expression returns the subset of rows from `data` where the value of `data.categ` equals `cat`.

(Seems possible the whole operation could be done more elegantly using `data.groupBy('categ').apply(someFunc)`.)

Answer (score 2):

It creates a boolean series with indexes where `data.categ` is equal to `cat` , with this boolean mask, you can filter your dataframe, in other words `subset` will have all records where the `categ` is the value stored in `cat`.

This is an example using numeric data

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.choice(np.arange(2), 5)
b = np.random.choice(np.arange(2), 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = a, b = b))


df[df.a == 0].head()

#   a   b
# 0 0   0
# 2 0   0
# 4 0   1

df[df.a == df.b].head()

#   a   b
# 0 0   0
# 2 0   0
# 3 1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it *is* a test.  Boolean expressions are *not* restricted to `if` statements.

It looks as if `data` is a data frame (PANDAS).  The expression used as a data frame index is how PANDAS denotes a selector or filter.  This says to select every row in which the fieled `categ` matches the variable `cat` (apparently a pre-defined variable).  This collection of rows becomes a new data frame, `subset`.

Answer (score 2):

`data.categ == cat` will return a boolean list that will be used to filter your dataframe by lefting only values where boolean is equal `True`.

Booleans are used in many situations, not only in `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are checking `data.categ` with the element iterating, `cat`, in the dictionary of `data`.
And if they are equal you are continuing the loop.