# Value Error due to ambiguity for an IF statement in OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

The code below finds a contour based on its maximum area but when there is no contour to be found I solve the `ValueError` by inputting `default = None` as shown in the code below. However, when the list is not empty (contour is present) a new `ValueError` arises as `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Why is that?

```
contours = cv2.findContours(tframe, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) == 2:
    contours = contours[0]
else:
    contours = contours[1]

maxcontour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, default= None)   #filter maximum contour based on contour area 

if maxcontour == None :
    maxarea = 0
    circularity.append(0)
    area.append(0)
    
else:
    maxarea = cv2.contourArea(maxcontour)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(maxcontour,True)
    M = cv2.moments(maxcontour)    #moments of that contour
    circ = circularityfunc(maxarea,perimeter)    #function that calculates circularity of contour 
    circularity.append(circ)
```

Comment: always test for none with the expressions "is None" or "is not None", never use == to test for None.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz that helped! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because if contours are present, `maxcontour` is a NumPy array, if there are no contours, `maxcontour` is `None` as per default parameter.

So, when you check `if maxcontour == None` it could happen that you are comparing a NumPy array with `None`.

**Read this thread for more info:** [Comparing two NumPy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

---

**One possible solution** is to use `[]` as default

`maxcontour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, default= [])`

then check the length:

`if len(maxcontour) == 0:`