# Comparing NumPy Arrays (predicted vs actual labels)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, label, prediction

I am having issues comparing 2 numPy arrays against each other. I am currently doing a classification task and have classified data into either 1's or 0's. I want to compare the predictions against the actual label.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPZq.png)

attached is an image of the two arrays. I cannot seem to find a way .

though not ideal, I have tried the following:

```
for i in range(len(yTrain)):
    yTrain==yPred
```

I was hoping that it would return a bunch of true and false values which I could manually tally up but that didn't work.

I would like an output which counts the number of inaccuracies. e.g. out of 200 datapoints, 45 were misclassified or something along those lines

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two NumPy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

Comment: Please post small sample arrays as text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the count of where `yTrain == yPred`, you can use [`np.count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
matches = np.count_nonzero(yTrain == yPred)
mismatches = yTrain.size - matches
```